# Mailgun attachment from url - who is reading the stream?

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I've a question for those with experience sending high volumes of email with attachments. One of the attachments option is to pass a stream from an url, using node module:

```
var request = require('request');
var file = request("https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!',
  attachment: file
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
   console.log(body);
});
```

Will my server download the stream and send it over to mailgun or will mailgun just receive the url string from my server and download the stream there?

Any advice on how to send high volume of emails with attachments?

Thanks!
T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailgun will read the stream and send the file as an attachment.

Mailgun will manage the sending to ensure you do not get flagged as a spammer. I would just do an asynchronous loop and send out the messages.

Comment: thanks, I was not able to find a reference for it, is it written somewhere? Otherwise if it's from your own experience I'll take it (I just want to be sure I'm not downloading thousands of times the same image or stuff like that)

Comment: @T.Rossi - The documentation mentions that you can use a stream to attach a file from the internet https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js. I can also confirm that it works from experience.